# Sending email using charset encoding UTF-8 - Python + boto3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, boto, aws-lambda

I am using S3 Lambda (python + boto3) + AWS SES  to create an auto-reply email.

Sending an email from my computer everything works ok. I can see in the email the correct string. "Olá, meu nome é Pedro". If i print to console inside python, still in my computer, the string is ok too.

When the email is triggered from lambda I am getting charset enconding/decoding problems, like "OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro".
If inside python in lambda s3 console, i make a print I see the wrong string: "OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro"

Do I need to set another property in the email header?

See the source code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
body = u"Olá, meu nome é Pedro"               
body = body.encode('UTF-8')
response = client.send_email(
    Source='teste@emporiodacerveja.com.br',
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [
        "pedrorjbr@gmail.com",
        ]
    },

    Message={
        'Subject': {
        'Data': 'Entre em Contato com Nossa Central de Atendimento',
        'Charset': 'UTF-8'
        },
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Data': body ,
                'Charset': 'UTF-8'
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: what code do you use to print the string? Have you removed `body.encode('utf-8')` as I've suggested in my answer? What happens if you run `print(u'Ol\xe1, meu nome \xe9 Pedro')`?

Comment: print (body). I already removed the body.encode('utf-8'). If i run print(u'Ol\xe1, meu nome \xe9 Pedro') it print correctly!

Comment: Now it works!! I made: body = u'Ol\xe1, meu nome \xe9 Pedro' and then use body.encode("utf-8"). How do i transform my string to this format scapping special characters.

Comment: If you have specified the encoding declaration correctly i.e., if it says `coding: utf-8` then you should make sure that your Python *source code* is saved as `utf-8`. It has *nothing* to do with `.encode('utf-8')` (the encoding at runtime is independent). To see the text representation of the Unicode string, just type it in a REPL or `print repr(u"Olá")` (Python 2) or `print(ascii("Olá"))` (in Python 3). Does it continue to work if you pass Unicode string instead of bytes as `body` (if you drop `.encode('utf-8')`)?

Comment: Sebastian, I first encode it using latin-1 and the encode it using utf-8 and now it works!!! Thanks!!

Comment: you should not use both latin-1 and utf-8 here. It treats symptoms, not the root cause (e.g., the Python source code encoding might be corrupted during an ftp transfer or you might have edited the file in `notepad.exe` and it saved your Python script using Windows ANSI encoding such as `cp1252` instead of `utf-8`).

Comment: I dont how o verify if my code is saved as utf-8 or cp1252. I am using a web interface from AWS lambda to create the code.

Comment: `assert u"Olá, meu nome é Pedro" == u'Ol\xe1, meu nome \xe9 Pedro'` verifies (in this case) that the encoding declaration is correct. If the web interface uses a different encoding then set the appropriate encoding declaration e.g., `# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-`.

Answer (score 1):

What you see (`"OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro"`) is called [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). It is created then the text in one encoding is interpreted as text in another (incompatible) character encoding:

```
>>> print(u"Olá, meu nome é Pedro".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1'))
OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro
```

To avoid such errors, pass Unicode strings around, not bytes (drop `.encode('utf-8')`). If `.send_email()` doesn't accept Unicode here then it might indicate a bug.

Comment: So i just comment the line: 'body = body.encode('UTF-8')' but i still receiving OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro. I tryed to remove "UTF-8" from charset header.

Comment: @PedroMagalhaes: you might also send/receive correct data but you might display it incorrectly. What happens if you try to display: `body = u"Olá, meu nome é Pedro"`?

Comment: It is printing: OlÃ¡ meu nome Ã© Pedro. 
In my computer it is printing right: "Olá, meu nome é Pedro"

Comment: [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33304027/edit) your question and specify exactly where do you see `OlÃ¡, meu nome Ã© Pedro` and what code prints it ([create a minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))